# How do I use groupby on continuous similar values for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say we have a data frame called df:

```
A   B 
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
2   e
1   f
1   g
```

I'd like to use groupby to create the following :

```
1: [a,b,c]
2: [d,e]
1: [f,g]
```

Currently if I use something on the lines of

```
{k: list(v) for k,v in df.groupby("A")["B"]}
```

I get

```
1: [a,b,c,f,g]
2: [d,e]
```

I'd like the separation to be based on the data being both similar and continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted column `A` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
print (df["A"].ne(df["A"].shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
Name: A, dtype: int32

df = df["B"].groupby(df["A"].ne(df["A"].shift()).cumsum()).apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
   A          B
0  1  [a, b, c]
1  2     [d, e]
2  3     [f, g]
```

For `dict`:

```
d = {k: list(v) for k,v in df['B'].groupby(df["A"].ne(df["A"].shift()).cumsum())}
print (d)
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'e'], 3: ['f', 'g']}
```

---

```
d  = df["B"].groupby(df["A"].ne(df["A"].shift()).cumsum()).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'e'], 3: ['f', 'g']}
```

EDIT1:

```
df  = df["B"].groupby([df['A'], df["A"].ne(df["A"].shift()).cumsum()]).apply(list)
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]).to_dict()
print (df)
{1: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'g']], 2: ['d', 'e']}
```

Comment: Nice one! Very elegant!

Comment: Thanks

Is there a way to modify and use  the 
    {k: list(v) for k,v in df.groupby("A")["B"]}
structure? 

Also, I'd like it to show as 
`A    B
1     [a,b,c]
2    [d,e]
1    [f.g]`

(last element as 1, not 3). Thanks again.

Comment: But there is problem, becuse in `dict` cannot be duplicates keys try `{1:[2,3], 1:[5,7]}`

Comment: ah, in that case, would it be possible to have {1: [ [a,b,c] , [f,g] ], 2:[d,e]} ? as a list of lists, for same but separated keys? Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Thanks !

Comment: Is there any way to group this to include another following column